# Заполните массив из 30 элементов случайными числами на отрезке [10; 12] и найдите самую длинную последовательность стоящих рядом одинаковых элементов

Tags: python

Заполните массив из 30 элементов случайными числами на отрезке [10; 12] и найдите самую длинную последовательность стоящих рядом одинаковых элементов. Если таких последовательностей несколько выведите последнюю из них.

Например, для массива из 10 элементов, имеющих значения 10, 10, 11, 10, 12, 12,  11,  12, 11, 10  программа должна вывести  12, 12.

```
from random import randint

arr = [randint(10,12) for i in range(30)]

lst = []

n = 1

for i,x in enumerate(arr[:-1]):
  if x == arr[i+1]:
    n +=1
  else:
    lst.append(( x,n ))
    n = 1
 
max_el = max( lst, key=lambda x: x[1] )

print('массив : ',arr)

print("число : {}  {}".format( max_el[0], max_el[1] ))
```

Comment: А вопрос-то какой?

Comment: надо чтоб был вывод 12 12

Comment: типо если в массиве 12 12 12 12

Comment: то вывод 12 12 12 12

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint

arr = [randint(10,12) for i in range(30)]

lst = []

n = 1

for i,x in enumerate(arr[:-1]):
  if x == arr[i+1]:
    n +=1
  else:
    lst.append(( x,n ))
    n = 1
 
max_el = max( lst, key=lambda x: x[1] )

print('массив : ',arr)

print("число:", *[max_el[0]] * max_el[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint

arr = [randint(10, 12) for i in range(30)]
lst = []
n = 1

for i,x in enumerate(arr[:-1]):
    if x == arr[i+1]:
        n +=1
    else:
        lst.append(( x,n ))
        n = 1
 
max_el = max( lst, key=lambda x: x[1] )

print('массив arr: \n', arr)
print("\nчисло: {}; {} - раз/а".format( max_el[0], max_el[1] ))

_f = '{} ' * max_el[1]
ind_lst = lst.index(( max_el[0], max_el[1] ))
ind_1_item = sum([ i for v, i in lst[0:ind_lst] ])
_sliz = arr[ind_1_item : ind_1_item+max_el[1]]

print("\nсамая длинная последовательность: {}".format(_f).format(*_sliz))
```